# sudo hangs and NetworkManager not starting

Tags: 20.04, sudo

Since two weeks I am experiencing troubles when booting Ubuntu 20.04 (I have a dual boot with Windows 10). Booting up takes longer than usual, in particular it hangs for approx 30 seconds after I entered my password on a black screen with only a cursor. After I while I boot to desktop, but the internet connection does not connect. Upon investigation of the *Network* tab in Settings, it says that *NetworkManager needs to be running*.

I could mitigate this problem by resetting my system to a previous version with *TimeShift*. This would restore system files from a backup, and it would work until I rebooted again. Then the issue would arise again and I would need to reset with TimeShift again.

Today I totally reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 from an USB-stick hoping this would solve the problem. It worked fine, until I rebooted again. Then the same issue reappeared. Upon further investigation I noticed that I could also not run `sudo` commands. The terminal just hangs after I type `sudo`. I ran `strace sudo`, which gave me the following output:

```
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=256, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=1024*1024, rlim_max=1024*1024}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NPROC, NULL, {rlim_cur=256566, rlim_max=256566}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=256566, rlim_max=256566}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_RSS, NULL, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_RSS, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
fcntl(0, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(1, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(2, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5703712, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 5703712, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f0fdbb70000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2940, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2940, ...}) = 0
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2940
lseek(3, -1846, SEEK_CUR)               = 1094
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 1846
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/etc/sudo.conf", 0x7fffc9da7300)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
geteuid()                               = 1000
access("/usr/local/sbin/sudo", X_OK)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/local/bin/sudo", X_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/sbin/sudo", X_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/bin/sudo", X_OK)           = 0
stat("/usr/bin/sudo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|S_ISUID|0755, st_size=166056, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2996, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2996
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "sudo", 4sudo)                     = 4
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "effective uid is not 0, is /usr/"..., 133effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?) = 133
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=256, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, {rlim_cur=1024*1024, rlim_max=1024*1024}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NPROC, NULL, {rlim_cur=256566, rlim_max=256566}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NPROC, {rlim_cur=256566, rlim_max=256566}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_RSS, NULL, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_RSS, {rlim_cur=RLIM64_INFINITY, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, NULL, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}, NULL) = 0
fcntl(0, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(1, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(2, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5703712, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 5703712, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f0fdbb70000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2940, ...}) = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2940, ...}) = 0
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2940
lseek(3, -1846, SEEK_CUR)               = 1094
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\16\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 1846
close(3)                                = 0
stat("/etc/sudo.conf", 0x7fffc9da7300)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
geteuid()                               = 1000
access("/usr/local/sbin/sudo", X_OK)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/local/bin/sudo", X_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/sbin/sudo", X_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/usr/bin/sudo", X_OK)           = 0
stat("/usr/bin/sudo", {st_mode=S_IFREG|S_ISUID|0755, st_size=166056, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2996, ...}) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2996
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/sudo.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "sudo", 4sudo)                     = 4
write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
write(2, "effective uid is not 0, is /usr/"..., 133effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?) = 133
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

I googled for terms like `/usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges` and tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1580293/sudo-effective-uid-is-not-0-is-usr-bin-sudo-on-a-file-system-with-the-nosuid) in recovery mode but without succes. Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: What does `ls -l /etc/sudoers /usr/bin/sudo` return?

Comment: It returns:
`-r--r------- 1 root root 755 feb 3 2020 /etc/sudoers` 

`-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 166056 jul 15 02:17 /usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: `-rwsr-xr-x` is equivalent to octal `4755`, no chmod required. The error you are seeing under `strace` is normal I think... and just reflects the fact that `sudo` is being run under a non-privileged `strace` process.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. How can I run it as a privileged process?

Comment: Unfortunately the issue also persists after downgrading to 18.04